# How do I compute cross-app URLs in a Pyramid composite project?

Tags: python, url-routing, pyramid

I'm using Pyramid to develop a large web project comprised of multiple apps, joined together using the composite app feature, and I want to generate navigation links on my home page to point to the different apps. My INI file starts like this:

```
[composite:main]
use = egg:Paste#urlmap
/ = home
/app1 = myapp1
/app2 = myapp2

[app:home]
use = egg:myproject#home

[app:myapp1]
use = egg:myproject#myapp1

[app:myapp2]
use = egg:myproject#myapp2

...
```

Within a given app, I use `request.route_url('view_name')` to generate URLs and the code correctly prepends `/` or `/app1` or `/app2` to whatever URL is defined within the application by `config.add_route(...)`.

I use the `home` app as the landing page for the website at `/`, and I want to do something like `request.route_url('app1.index')` within a `home` template to generate a link to the `index` view in `app1`. When I try this, however, I get `KeyError: 'No such route named app1.index'` from the template.

My workaround is to hard-code the paths into my home page nav links, but I'd rather not do this, since those paths are already defined in my project's .ini configuration.

Is there a way to do this in Pyramid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a not a standard solution. The approach I have used personally is to define cross-links between apps in my config file and I wrote some code to automatically inject them into my apps as static routes (see `static=True` on `config.add_route`) which allows you to use `request.route_url` to generate urls external to your app.

Thus I build a config that looks like this:

```
[composite:main]
use = egg:Paste#urlmap
/ = home
/app1 = myapp1
/app2 = myapp2

[app:home]
use = egg:myproject#home
links =
    app1 /app1
    app2 /app2

[app:myapp1]
use = egg:myproject#myapp1
links =
    home /
    app2 /app2

[app:myapp2]
use = egg:myproject#myapp2
links =
    home /
    app1 /app1
```

You might find it tedious but I like the control it provides on a per-app basis. You could alternatively probably define this in the `[DEFAULT]` section of the file and inherit it between apps.

The idea is that this config will allow me to do `request.route_url('app1')`.

I use this code (place it into a file named something like `app_links.py` and include it via `config.include('.app_links')`:

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse

from pyramid.settings import aslist

def link_pregenerator(request, elements, kwargs):
    kwargs['_app_url'] = request.host_url
    return elements, kwargs

def includeme(config):
    settings = config.get_settings()

    links = aslist(settings.get('links', ''), flatten=False)
    for name, pattern in (item.split(' ', 1) for item in links):
        parsed = urlparse(pattern)
        if parsed.hostname:
            config.add_route(name, pattern, static=True)
        else:
            config.add_route(
                name, pattern,
                pregenerator=link_pregenerator,
                static=True,
            )
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your response @michael-merickel. I'll try this solution out later this week. (As a side note, since you mentioned the [DEFAULT] section, I haven't had much success with that in my composite app. I have started to wonder if [DEFAULT] gets overlooked in composite setups. I suppose I ought to ask that in another SO question.)

Comment: The values in the default section aren't automatically added to your app sections, you need to use the special "get local_name = global_name" syntax to pull in a value, or you need to merge it yourself in your main where you receive both `(global_config, **app_settings)`. You can read the PasteDeploy docs to know more about how it all works.

Comment: I'm accepting this as the answer since it gets the job done and also it helped me to better understand the pyramid configuration system. I like the idea of defining `links` in the `[DEFAULT]` section of the INI file and inheriting from there. If I end up doing that I'll report here on how it works.